# Getting an error when testing my grammar program

Tags: java, listener, calculator, antlr, grammar

I'm in the process of creating a programming language using ANTLR4 to create a simlpe calculator.
I am pretty much stuck on this error, I've been looking around, but can't seem to fix it, any suggestions/help?

I've been looking through my java file, but can't understand why it gives me that error.

```
$ make test 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:18) 
at Interpreter.visitWhileLoop(main.java:79) 
at Interpreter.visitWhileLoop(main.java:47) 
at implParser$WhileLoopContext.accept(implParser.java:377) 
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:18) 
at Interpreter.visitStart(main.java:52)
at Interpreter.visitStart(main.java:47) 
at implParser$StartContext.accept(implParser.java:123) 
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:18) 
at main.main(main.java:38) 
make: *** [Makefile:18: test] Error 1
```

Here's the part where I implement my grammar methods to my main.java:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeVisitor;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import java.io.IOException;
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

// we expect exactly one argument: the name of the input file
if (args.length!=1) {
    System.err.println("\n");
    System.err.println("Simple calculator\n");
    System.err.println("=================\n\n");
    System.err.println("Please give as input argument a filename\n");
    System.exit(-1);
}
String filename=args[0];

// open the input file
CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(filename);
    //new ANTLRFileStream (filename); // depricated

// create a lexer/scanner
implLexer lex = new implLexer(input);

// get the stream of tokens from the scanner
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);

// create a parser
implParser parser = new implParser(tokens);

// and parse anything from the grammar for "start"
ParseTree parseTree = parser.start();

// Construct an interpreter and run it on the parse tree
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.visit(parseTree);
}
}
// We write an interpreter that implements interface
// "implVisitor<T>" that is automatically generated by ANTLR
// This is parameterized over a return type "<T>" which is in our case
// simply a Double.
class Interpreter extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<Double> implements implVisitor<Double> {
static Environment env=new Environment();
public Double visitStart(implParser.StartContext ctx){
for(implParser.CommandContext c:ctx.cs) visit(c);
return null;
};

public Double visitSingleCommand(implParser.SingleCommandContext ctx){
return visit(ctx.c);
}

public Double visitMultipleCommands(implParser.MultipleCommandsContext ctx){
for(implParser.CommandContext c:ctx.cs) visit(c);
return null;
}

public Double visitAssignment(implParser.AssignmentContext ctx){
Double v=visit(ctx.e);
env.setVariable(ctx.x.getText(),v);
return null;
}

public Double visitOutput(implParser.OutputContext ctx){
Double v=visit(ctx.e);
System.out.println(v);
return null;
}

public Double visitWhileLoop(implParser.WhileLoopContext ctx){
while(visit(ctx.c).equals(1.0)){
    visit(ctx.p);
}
return null;
}
public Double visitIfStatement(implParser.IfStatementContext ctx){
while(visit(ctx.c1).equals(1.0)){
    visit(ctx.p1);
}
return null;
}
/*public Double visitSubstraction(implParser.SubstractionContext ctx) {
return visit(ctx.e1);
}
public Double visitDivison(implParser.DivisonContext ctx) {
return visit(ctx.e1);
}*/
 public Double visitMUL(implParser.MULContext ctx) {
    Double left = this.visit(ctx.expr(0));
    Double right = this.visit(ctx.expr(1));
    switch (ctx.op.getType()) {
        case implParser.MULT:
            return left * right;
        case implParser.DIV:
            return left / right;
        case implParser.MOD:
            return left % right;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("unknown operator: " + implParser.tokenNames[ctx.op.getType()]);
    }
}

public Double visitOP(implParser.OPContext ctx) {
    Double left = this.visit(ctx.expr(0));
    Double right = this.visit(ctx.expr(1));
    switch (ctx.op.getType()) {
        case implParser.PLUS:
            //return left && right;
                    return left + right;
        case implParser.MINUS:
            return left - right;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("unknown operator: " + implParser.tokenNames[ctx.op.getType()]);
    }
}

public Double visitParenthesis(implParser.ParenthesisContext ctx){
return visit(ctx.e);
};

public Double visitVariable(implParser.VariableContext ctx){
return env.getVariable(ctx.x.getText());
};
/*public Double visitAddition(implParser.AdditionContext ctx){
return visit(ctx.e1)+visit(ctx.e2);
};

public Double visitMultiplication(implParser.MultiplicationContext ctx){
return visit(ctx.e1)*visit(ctx.e2);
};
*/
public Double visitConstant(implParser.ConstantContext ctx){
return Double.parseDouble(ctx.c.getText()); 
};

public Double visitUnequal(implParser.UnequalContext ctx){
Double v1=visit(ctx.e1);
Double v2=visit(ctx.e2);
if (v1.equals(v2))  return 0.0;
else return 1.0;
}
public Double visitEqual(implParser.EqualContext ctx){
Double v1=visit(ctx.e1);
Double v2=visit(ctx.e2);
if (v1.equals(v2))  return 0.0;
else return 1.0;
}
public Double visitLess(implParser.LessContext ctx){
Double v1=visit(ctx.e1);
Double v2=visit(ctx.e2);
if (v1.equals(v2))  return 0.0;
else return 1.0;
}
public Double visitLessOrEqual(implParser.LessOrEqualContext ctx){
Double v1=visit(ctx.e1);
Double v2=visit(ctx.e2);
if (v1.equals(v2))  return 0.0;
else return 1.0;
}
public Double visitGreater(implParser.GreaterContext ctx){
Double v1=visit(ctx.e1);
Double v2=visit(ctx.e2);
if (v1.equals(v2))  return 0.0;
else return 1.0;
}
public Double visitGreaterOrEqual(implParser.GreaterOrEqualContext ctx){
Double v1=visit(ctx.e1);
Double v2=visit(ctx.e2);
if (v1.equals(v2))  return 0.0;
else return 1.0;
}
public Double visitAND(implParser.ANDContext ctx){
Double v1=visit(ctx.e1);
Double v2=visit(ctx.e2);
if (v1.equals(v2))  return 0.0;
else return 1.0;
}
public Double visitOR(implParser.ORContext ctx){
Double v1=visit(ctx.e1);
Double v2=visit(ctx.e2);
if (v1.equals(v2))  return 0.0;
else return 1.0;
}
public Double visitNum(implParser.NumContext ctx){
    return null;
}
}
/*
class Expr{};
class var extends Expr{}; //Subclass
class Const extends Expr{}; //Subclass
class Multiplication extends Expr{}; //Subclass*/
```

The following errors are:

```
public Double visitStart(implParser.StartContext ctx){
[52]for(implParser.CommandContext c:ctx.cs) visit(c);
return null;
};

public Double visitWhileLoop(implParser.WhileLoopContext ctx){
while(visit(ctx.c).equals(1.0)){
[79]  visit(ctx.p);
}
```

Comment: you have exception type and certain place in code where it occurs. What the issue then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: So apparently `ctx.p` is `null`. That will depend on your grammar and the test input, neither of which you include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:18) 
at Interpreter.visitWhileLoop(main.java:79) 
at Interpreter.visitWhileLoop(main.java:47) 
at implParser$WhileLoopContext.accept(implParser.java:377) 
...
```

It means a NullPointerException has occurred in the `visit()` method of AbstractParseTreeVisitor. It was caused by a call from the context of `visitWhileLoop()`, which was itself called from the context of `visitWhileLoop()`. It looks like a recursive call, but the line numbers for the errors make it seem like there are two separate methods. The code you posted only seemed to have one method called `visitWhileLoop()`, so I'm not sure what's going on there.

```
public Double visitWhileLoop(implParser.WhileLoopContext ctx){
    while(visit(ctx.c).equals(1.0)){
        visit(ctx.p);
    }
    return null;
}
```

There are two calls to `visit()` from `visitWhileLoop()`. I would guess that one or other of them is passing in a `null` to `visit()`. In other words, the value of `ctx.c` or `ctx.p` is `null`.

You could run this in an IDE's debugger with a breakpoint on the `visitWhileLoop()` method to find out more information about what's happening.